# Gitlab ci installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab, gitlab-ci

why do i get this error when installing gitlab ci below when i install gitlab-ci

can any one put me in right direction i have done mothing from the installation page and will like to use postgress which is on a remote server and nginx which is also on a remote server:

Thanks

```
rake aborted!
Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor @ fptr_finalize - /home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/1.9.1/io/open.rb
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/1.9.1/io/open.rb:2:in `close'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/1.9.1/io/open.rb:2:in `open'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/1.9.1/io/open.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:22:in `block in require_relative_dir'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:21:in `each'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:21:in `require_relative_dir'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/1.9.1/io.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:22:in `block in require_relative_dir'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:21:in `each'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:21:in `require_relative_dir'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/1.9.1.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/1.9.2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/1.9.3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/1.9.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/2.0.0.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/2.0.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/coercible-0.2.0/lib/coercible.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/virtus-1.0.0/lib/virtus.rb:225:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/grape-0.6.1/lib/grape.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credit goes to Brian Hartvigsen, as I came to this answer from his post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960872/windows-puma-unable-to-load-application-due-to-backports-bad-file-descriptor/25983748#25983748)

Edit the Gemfile.lock

```
sudo -u gitlab_ci -H vi ~/Gemfile.lock
```

And replace the backports line with 'backports (3.6.1)'

Then reinstall the bundle

```
# For MySQL (note, the option says "without ... postgres")
sudo -u gitlab_ci -H bundle install --without development test postgres --deployment

# Or for PostgreSQL (note, the option says "without ... mysql")
sudo -u gitlab_ci -H bundle install --without development test mysql --deployment
```